# What do Oleg Ershov's winning photos show?

Tags: competitions

So I came by two photos on [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/in-pictures-51386024), and I can't figure out what they're for, even from the [competition website](https://www.internationallandscapephotographer.com/) (I'm not affiliated).

The first (Fleswick Bay, England) is hard to grasp due to an object that appears to be a pebble, which creates a sort of illusion; the second (Blafellsa, Iceland) I'm not sure if overhead of a big area, or a macro shot.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try googling Fleswick Bay maybe? It took me [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Bees_Head#/media/File:St_bees_head_fleswick_bay_wave_cut_platform.JPG): an image of rock on the beach that's been smoothed by the sea. Stick a pebble in it on a dry day and with good light, and you might get something like Oleg's photo.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is supposedly a "photo ... of a stone in the sand in Fleswick Bay, England."
(according to [Mother Nature Network](https://www.mnn.com/earth-matters/wilderness-resources/blogs/photos-international-landscape-photographer-year-winners))

According to [Olev's 500px page](https://500px.com/photo/1003725661/Iceland-34-by-Oleg-Ershov?ctx_page=1&from=user&user_id=213212), the second one was taken with a Canon EOS 5DS R using a Canon EF 24-70mm f/2.8L II USM at 70mm, ƒ/18, 1/15s, so

Answer (score 2):

They show me, and hopefully you, how

*the use of selective composition of showing only part of a scene instead of the more recognizable broader scene in order to draw attention to patterns*

can ( and should ) lead us to interesting and **thought provoking contemplation** of what we are seeing. *I.E. what are they showing us* ?